# convergence of a numerical series using information about an entire series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm on a problem that seems simple but turns out to be a bit twisted.

Let be $\sum_{n\epsilon N }^{}{u_nz^n}$ a power series with radius of convergence ρ = 1. Which of the following statements are true? which are false?

1. $\sum_{n\epsilon N}^{}{u_n(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n}$ converges.
2. $\sum_{n\epsilon N}^{}{u_n(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n}$ diverges.

I've tried to use that $\frac{u_n+1}{u_n}=1$ thanks to alembert test but i have nothing convincing.

Does anyone have any ideas? Or even a solution? Please let me know. Thank you very much and good evening.

Comment: Why should 1. and 2. be true or not true? Both seems to be possible.

Comment: Could you please explain? It seems to depend on Un

Comment: Sorry, but this question isn't appropriate for mathoverflow. I think it will be closed soon. Its a good question at a more elementary level.

Comment: Ok sorry for disturbing, wishing you all the best.

Comment: @Zak not a problem, it's a mistake many people make. Have a go at math.stackexchange instead. Best of luck with your studies! :-)

Comment: Apply the root test instead of the ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

Both statement may be true or false, depending on $u_n$.

For example, if $u_n=1$, then both series diverges. But if $u_n = \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, both series converges.